# Could not recognise discriminant 0xD for type Section

Tags: webassembly

I am trying to use `wasm-split` utility provided by Sentry (https://github.com/getsentry/symbolicator/tree/master/crates/wasm-split) like this:

```
./wasm-split-Windows-x86_64.exe main.wasm
```

`main.wasm` was compiled from C++ by emscripten.

However I get the following error:

```
Error: (root)[4]: Could not recognise discriminant 0xD for type Section

Caused by:
    Could not recognise discriminant 0xD for type Section
```

I have no idea what this means or where to go next from here. Google did not provide any answers either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question. This is a bug in `wasmbin`, a dependency of `wasm-split`. See here: https://github.com/getsentry/symbolicator/issues/969